# Classic ASP - Sorting files by vote in a for each loop

Tags: asp-classic

What I need to do is mark the output of 3 files that have the highest vote count, the problem being is that the files are not listed in the database, but the votes are.

So at the moment, the script goes over the files in a specific directory and prints out their file name and also prints what that files vote is with the following script.

```
Set fileSystem = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
set objFolder = fileSystem.GetFolder(strFolder)

For Each objFile in objFolder.Files
    Response.Write objFile.Name
Next
```

That works fine and dandy I also have another bit of code that uses SQL to get the file names vote count

```
SELECT count(*) AS total FROM votes WHERE filename=objFile.Name
```

If I put this inside the For Each loop, it prints out the votes for the file name.

Here is where I come into a problem, if I have 10 file names inside that folder, how do I echo 1st, 2nd and 3rd to the file names that have the top 3 votes?

Comment: I have to ask why you are doing it in this order? Why not query the database for the top 3 first (assuming the file name is stored in the database) and then find the files (or have I totally missed the question)?

Comment: Because each day files are put into new directories, but its not stored in the database, so if i was to query the DB theres no way to query based on date or anything

Comment: Now I'm Lost. If the database doesn't store the file name, why does your SQL query search by the file name?

Comment: Yeh, im totally lost as well haha ... it does hold the filename, just not any details about when it was put in

Comment: Are all the files in question stored in one folder or in different directories?

Comment: The ones for today are kept in a folder called 'current' .. then once it moves on to tomorrow, all teh files get moved to a dated folder .... its all backwards

Comment: and your query is only about those files for the day?

Comment: The query only querys the DB based on the filenames that are in the 'current' directory

Comment: I don't know why you need to read the files on disk at all; the  database stores the file name, you know the directory (current) and the database also stores the votes! Something like `SELECT TOP 3 count(*) AS total FROM votes WHERE filename=objFile.Name order by votes` (SQL not my strongest but this should give a good idea, although you may need to do some grouping as you have a count)

Comment: How would you go about it?

Comment: Yes but how would i get the objFile.Name if it wasnt in a loop?

Comment: I understand that ... but if every single filename / vote is kept in the database with no reference to if its current or not, then theres no way of just printing out the current filenames, instead it will print out every single one in the DB and that is thousands

Comment: Ah, right! You're saying that the database holds data for files in the "current" folder and not in the current folder, and as such you need to make that match first?

Comment: Sort of ... The database has the following fields ( id, filename, votes ) and thats it ... There are thousands and thousands of records ... The folder that holds the current files may only have 10 in there at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I first read the question but in the comments you give important further Information. Try to give all Information in your question otherwise one has to read through all the comments.

Anyway would this be a solution? Generally you read all the file names from the current folder and put them in a comma separated string variable. Then use that variable in your SQL.

```vbs
<%
Set fileSystem = server.createobject("scripting.filesystemobject")
set objFolder = fileSystem.GetFolder(strFolder)

For Each objFile in objFolder.Files
    filter = filter & "'" & objFile.name & "'" & ", "
Next
' remove last comma
filter = left( filter, len(filter-2) )


sql = "SELECT top 3 filename FROM votes where filename in(" & filter & ") order by votes desc"

''execute sql and put results in recordset
''
%>
```

Comment: Is there any chance you could hook me up with a code sample as the logic for this is doing my head in and im not understanding at all. Thank you

Comment: That will only get the top 3 filenames though yeh? ... I need to print out all the filenames ( there could be 10+ ) and just echo 1st, 2nd and 3rd on the top 3

Comment: What do you mean, just echo the top 3?